# How to send 1 attachment from memory stream to 2 email addresses?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, memory, stream

I created content of a file like a string:

```
string fileContent = CreateContent();
```

Then I created `Attachment`:

```
Attachment fileAttachment = null;
var stream = new MemoryStream();
var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileContent))
{
    writer.Write(fileContent);
    writer.Flush();
    fileAttachment = new Attachment(
        stream,
        attachmentName,
        MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain);
}
```

After this, I sent the email:

```
SendEmail.SendEmailWithFile(strEmailSubject, fromEmail, fileAttachment);
```

and close:

```
writer.Close();
stream.Close();
```

Looks like everything is OK. But it isn't.
The problem is that `SendEmailWithFile` method should send `fileAttachment` to 2 different persons:

```
Public Sub SendEmailWithFile(strEmailSubject, fromEmail, fileAttachment)
 Dim emlEmail As Net.Mail.MailMessage = s.GetMailMessage()
 Dim smtp As Net.Mail.SmtpClient = New Net.Mail.SmtpClient
 emlEmail.To.Add(user.EmailAddress)
 ...
 If fileAttachmentIsNot Nothing Then
    emlEmail.Attachments.Add(fileAttachment)
 End If
 smtp.Send(emlEmail)//1

 If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(configurationManager.AppSettings("additionalEmailTo")) Then
  emlEmail.To.Clear()
  Dim address As String = configurationManager.AppSettings("additionalEmailTo")
  emlEmail.To.Add(address)
  smtp.Send(emlEmail)//2
 End If
End Sub
```

Emails send without errors but first email (//1) - contains empty file and the second(//2) contains full file.

What should I do to send correct file to both email addresses?

Comment: If I delete statments: writer.Close();stream.Close(); then everything works fine. What Do you think, guys? Is it right not to close memorystream?

Answer (score 1):

Why send it twice? You can either use `emlEmail.To.Add` to add more recipients or if you dont want them to see eachothers email address, use the BCC class.

```
Public Sub SendEmailWithFile(strEmailSubject, fromEmail, fileAttachment)
 Dim emlEmail As Net.Mail.MailMessage = s.GetMailMessage()
 Dim smtp As Net.Mail.SmtpClient = New Net.Mail.SmtpClient
 emlEmail.To.Add(user.EmailAddress)
 If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(configurationManager.AppSettings("additionalEmailTo")) Then
  Dim address As String = configurationManager.AppSettings("additionalEmailTo")
  emlEmail.To.Add(address)
 End If
...
 If fileAttachmentIsNot Nothing Then
    emlEmail.Attachments.Add(fileAttachment)
 End If
 smtp.Send(emlEmail)//1
 End Sub
```

Comment: >>"if you dont want them to see eachothers email address, use the BCC class" - Oh, I forgot about BCC. I will try. thank you.

Comment: There are plenty of cases where you'd want to send the same file to multiple people in multiple separate emails.  I wanted to send out individual payslips to all staff with 1 or more extra attachments.  I didn't want to hit the disk for each attachment for each email being sent, so I read them into memory.  Sending out several thousand emails in quick succession.